# How to use bulk_create in django

Tags: django

I just learned that I can use `bulk_create` in django so that the query wont be too long and it will be fast rather than using `for loop` to add data to the database one by one.

The problem is, I don't know how to do it, please help me.

views.py:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        csv_form = UploadCSVFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if csv_form.is_valid():
            period = csv_form.cleaned_data.get('period')
            print(period)
            period = SchoolPeriod.objects.get(period = period)
            # save csv file
            uploaded_file = csv_form.cleaned_data.get('file_name')
            save_csv = GradeCSVFile.objects.create(file_name= uploaded_file)

            csv_file = GradeCSVFile.objects.get(grades_uploaded= False)

            #read csv file
            with open(csv_file.file_name.path, 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)

                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 0:
                        pass
                    else:
                        subject = Subject.objects.get(subject_name = row[3])
                        profile = get_object_or_404(StudentProfile, LRN_or_student_number = row[0])


         ######### **THIS IS THE PART WHERE I NEED THE `BULK_CREATE` ** ############
                        new_grade = StudentGrade.objects.create(
                            student=profile.student.student,
                            period = period,
                            subject = subject,
                            grade = row[4],
                            )

            csv_file.grades_uploaded = True
            csv_file.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do here:

1. instantiate an empty list
2. loop over the rows in csv file
3. while looping through the rows, instantiate the object and assign it to a variable.
4. while looping through the rows append the variable to the list
5. after the loop: obj = mymodel.objects.bulk_create(list)

code:

```
            grade_list = []
            #read csv file
            with open(csv_file.file_name.path, 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)

                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 0:
                        pass
                    else:
                        subject = Subject.objects.get(subject_name = row[3])
                        profile = get_object_or_404(StudentProfile, LRN_or_student_number = row[0])

                        new_grade = StudentGrade(
                            student=profile.student.student,
                            period = period,
                            subject = subject,
                            grade = row[4],
                            )

                        grade_list.append(new_grade)

                        # this is slow
                        # new_grade = StudentGrade.objects.create(
                        #     student=profile.student.student,
                        #     period = period,
                        #     subject = subject,
                        #     grade = row[4],
                        #     )
                new_grades = StudentGrade.objects.bulk_create(grade_list)
```

If you don't want to use `bulk_create` you can use, `transaction.atomic`:

```
from django.db import transaction
                   with transaction.atomic():
                        new_grade = StudentGrade(
                            student=profile.student.student,
                            period = period,
                            subject = subject,
                            grade = row[4],
                            )
                        new_grade.save()
```